# How to load several files into R without overwriting the existing files?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Hi I would like to load into R several databases in .sas7bdat format. Each time a new database is loaded I would like to display its name (e.g. file.sas7bdat -> file). I wrote a code in R (shown below) but it does not work. I think it overwrites the existing database with a new database. I would be grateful for any suggestions how to improve it.

```
  getwd()
files<-list.files(pattern="*.sas7bdat")
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  data[i]<-read.sas7bdat(files[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any sad7bdat files handy, but this concept should translate across most of the `read.*` functions. You're on the right track with the for-loop, but can create the list directly by using `lapply()` like so:

```
#Make a few CSV files
x <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 2)
write.csv(x, "a.csv")
write.csv(x, "b.csv")

#Read them into a list
fileList <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.csv"), function(x) read.csv(x))

#check out what we ended up with
str(fileList)
#---
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ V1: num [1:5] -0.451 -0.317 -1.225 0.445 -1.361
  ..$ V2: num [1:5] 0.489 -2.8154 0.5147 -0.0561 0.826
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ V1: num [1:5] -0.451 -0.317 -1.225 0.445 -1.361
  ..$ V2: num [1:5] 0.489 -2.8154 0.5147 -0.0561 0.826
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(sas7bdat)

setwd(".... WHERE SAS FILES LIVES...")

load.sas <- function(x) {
    name <- strsplit(x,"\\.")[[1]][1]
    assign(name, read.sas7bdat(x), env=.GlobalEnv)
    TRUE
}   

sapply(list.files(path=".", pattern="*.sas7bdat", full.names=F), load.sas)`
```

You can add any futures to this code to revrite only some data or....